# What's difference between VS Code debug console and any web browser

Tags: javascript, browser, visual-studio-code

I have a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) file starts with `require()`, it works fine in the [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) by pressing F5 and it returns output in the Debug Console:

```
require('../src/FoxRandomString.js');
obj = FoxRandomString;
Tests = {
    obj: obj,
    canSetLength: function(){
        vals = [true,false,-1,'text',undefined,null,0,2,4,10]
        for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
            if (vals[i] < 4){
                if (this.obj.setLength(vals[i]) == 4){
                    console.log('%cFor input value = '+vals[i]+ ' Success. Output: '+this.obj.setLength(vals[i]),'color: white; background:olive')
                }
                else{
                    console.log('%cFor input value = '+vals[i]+ ' Fail. Output: '+this.obj.setLength(vals[i]),'color:black; background:red')
                }
            }
            else{
                if (this.obj.setLength(vals[i]) == vals[i] || isNaN(vals[i])){
                    console.log('%cFor input value = '+vals[i]+ ' Success. Output: '+this.obj.setLength(vals[i]),'color: white; background:olive')
                }
                else{
                    console.log('%cFor input value = '+vals[i]+ ' Fail. Output: '+this.obj.setLength(vals[i]),'color:black; background:red')
                }
            }            
        }

    }
}

Tests.canSetLength();
```

However, including this script in an HTML file using script tag and opening it in a browser such as Google Chrome, generate a console error about `require() is not defined`. I need to understand why does that occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because require() does not exist in the browser(client-side JavaScript).
You can use below options:

```
<script> tag.
CommonJS implementation, like Node.js
one more requireJS also can do the job done.
```

Comment: I still do not understand what's special that VS Code offers rather than the web browser to allow `require()` ?

Comment: @SaidbakR VS Code which has a Node.js runtime, require() is the Node.js stuff.